# How to do a IMAP UID SEARCH with JavaMail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am using JavaMail 1.5.1 and i want to do a `UID SEARCH`. Is this supported or do i have to issue a low level IMAP command via `((IMAPFolder) folder).doCommand(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[((UIDFolder)folder).getMessageByUID(uid)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessageByUID%28long%29)

Answer (score 0):

According with the docs, this is the way:

```
Folder f = store.getFolder("INBOX");
UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder)f;
Message msg = uf.getMessageByUID(uid);
```

You can find more here: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html